# WordPress infinite redirect loop when accessing wp-admin

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, nginx, infinite

I've just moved my wordpress blog on a new server. i reconfigured nginx conf files and the front end works great.
However when i try to access mywebsite.com/wp-admin area i get an infinite redirect loop but if i add index.php (mywebsite.com/wp-admin/index.php) it works. i'm pulling my hair because i can't figure out why nginx behave like that

I've already seen problems like this on the forum but in my case the conf file seem correct (its the same as on my old server)

I also disabled all my plugins (just in case) and i got the same behaviour

Here you can fin my nginx conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    root /home/mywebsite;
    index /index.php;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.mywebsite.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/www.mywebsite.com.error.log;
    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store (Mac). 
    # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
    location ~ /\. {
    deny all;
    } 

    # Deny access to any files with a .php extension in the uploads directory
    # Works in sub-directory installs and also in multisite network
    # Keep logging the requests to parse later (or to pass to firewall utilities such as fail2ban)
    location ~* /(?:uploads|files)/.*\.php$ {
    deny all;
    } 

    # WordPress single site rules.
    # Designed to be included in any server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if rules below fail.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri permanent;

# Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
#rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

# Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching plugin (if used).
#include global/wordpress-wp-super-cache.conf;
#include global/wordpress-w3-total-cache.conf;

#ss all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
    # This is a robust solution for path info security issue and works with "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1" in /etc/php.ini (default)
    #fastcgi_index /index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/mywebsite/dynamic$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
#   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}
```

Thank you for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is other wordpress instance already installed on the server. You need to rewrite nginx directives in ISPConfig as:

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

               # Add trailing slash to */wp-admin requests.
               rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;

               location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|css|js|ico)$ {
                    expires max;
                    log_not_found off;
               }
               # Deny public access to wp-config.php
               location ~* wp-config.php { 
                    deny all; 
               }

}
```

also include the same in subfolder. Usually its ISPConfig path is /home/admispconfig/ispconfig/lib/config.inc.php or you can search on your server

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time, no i don't have other wordpress instances on my server. i tried adding the "/" after $host$uri but i'm still facing the same issue :( any idea?